# Why all vertices are removed after useing the option ' Remove unreferenced vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices, 3d-reconstruction, meshlab

Im imported my pointcloud to Meshlab with normals and I would like to make a Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction. When I try to do this I Have a communicat like ' Filters requires correct per vertes normals. E.g.it is necessary that your ALL input vertices have a proper, not-null normal. If you enconuter this error on a triangulated mesh try to use  the *Remove Unreferenced Vertices filters.*...'

When I tried use this options all my vertices disappeared. I also checked my normals and all have not-null value.

I don't understand where the problem is. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is in .xyz format, you should have 6 numbers per vertex:

```
x coord, y coord, z coord, x normal, y normal, z normal
```

Most likely, your file only contains the coordinate data.
If you cannot add the normal information to the file, you can estimate it in Meshlab with:

```
Filters > Normals, Curvatures and Orientation > Compute normals for point sets
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not a triangulated mesh, so you should not call "Remove Unreferenced Vertices" filter. That filter will remove those vertex that are not in use by any triangle, which mean "every vertex" if you have no triangles.

Comment: So you have any idea why the normals are wrong ? or How can I try to fix it ?